# Change color related on value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table values populated from back-end

Here is js function that doing it.

```js
function AllProposals() {
  let getProposalsUrl = '/proposals/index';
  $.ajax({
      url: getProposalsUrl,
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      processData: false,
      success: function (data) {
          $("#proposals").empty();
          var list = data;
          for (var i = 0; i <= list.length - 1; i++) {
              var tableData = '<tr>' +
                  '<td class="proposalId">' +
                  list[i].Id +
                  '</td>' +
                  '<td > ' +
                  list[i].Project +
                  '</td>' +
                  '<td > ' +
                  moment(list[i].DateFrom).format('DD/MM/YYYY') + "--" + moment(list[i].DateTo).format('DD/MM/YYYY') +
                  '</td>' +
                  '<td> ' +
                  list[i].WorkTime + "--" +list[i].WorkTimeTo +
                  '</td>' +
                  '<td > ' +
                  list[i].Quantity+
                  '</td>' +
                  '<td> ' +
                  list[i].Service +
                  '</td>' +
                  '<td> ' +
                  list[i].Price +
                  '</td>' +
                  '<td> ' +
                  list[i].Status +
                  '</td>' +

                  '</tr>';
              $('#proposals').append(tableData);
          }
      }
  })
}
```

It working great.

Bu It need to check this value on flight

```
'<td> '+list[i].Status+'</td>' +
```

And if it is "Rejected" change text color to red.

How I can do this correctly?

Thank's for help.

Comment: can you add a class to the ``<td>``

Comment: You need to add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so we can help you.

Comment: But I need to change it only if  `list[i].Status` == "Rejected"@GerardoBLANCO

Comment: Only if ``<td>Rejected</td>`` right?

Comment: It's complete example, because I describe what I have and what I need to get @GerardoBLANCO

Comment: Yes, you're right@GerardoBLANCO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this code will need some refactoring if you will need to reuse the return data of the ajax call and in general it is not good looking, I would do as follows:

```
          '<td'+ (list[i].Status == 'Rejected' ? ' style="color:red;"' : '') +'> ' +
          list[i].Status +
          '</td>' +
```

**Edit**
If in future you will need to assign different colors based on the content of `list[i].Status`, I suggest to create a content-to-color lookup table:

```
let contentToColor = {
    "Rejected": "red",
    "Success": "green",
    "Warning": "yellow"
};
```

and then:

```
      '<td'+ (contentToColor[list[i].Status] !== 'undefined' ? ' style="color: '+ contentToColor[list[i].Status] +';"' : '') +'> ' +
      list[i].Status +
      '</td>' +
```

The way of checking the existence of the variable may be wrong, I don't remember how it is done in JS, but you get the concept.
Anyway, I would suggest to refactor the code by separating the presentation code and the domain code. You will save yourself by the ugly code I wrote above. I had to read it 10 times for checking if the quotes were good.

Comment: Tht's great solution, but what if in future I need to check value and change color related to this value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a switch to get the status and set the color base on what you get and pass it to a variable.

**Example**

```
<script>
function AllProposals() {
  let getProposalsUrl = '/proposals/index';
  $.ajax({
      url: getProposalsUrl,
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      processData: false,
      success: function (data) {
          $("#proposals").empty();
          var list = data;
          for (var i = 0; i <= list.length - 1; i++) {

              var mycolor = "";
              switch (list[i].Status) {
                    case "Approved":
                        mycolor = "style="color:green";
                        break;
                    case "Rejected":
                        mycolor = "style="color:red";
                        //Add more if needed
                }

              var tableData = '<tr>' +
                  '<td class="proposalId">' +
                  list[i].Id +
                  '</td>' +
                  '<td > ' +
                  list[i].Project +
                  '</td>' +
                  '<td > ' +
                  moment(list[i].DateFrom).format('DD/MM/YYYY') + "--" + moment(list[i].DateTo).format('DD/MM/YYYY') +
                  '</td>' +
                  '<td> ' +
                  list[i].WorkTime + "--" +list[i].WorkTimeTo +
                  '</td>' +
                  '<td > ' +
                  list[i].Quantity+
                  '</td>' +
                  '<td> ' +
                  list[i].Service +
                  '</td>' +
                  '<td> ' +
                  list[i].Price +
                  '</td>' +
                  '<td' + mycolor +'> ' +
                  list[i].Status +
                  '</td>' +

                  '</tr>';
              $('#proposals').append(tableData);
          }
      }
  })
}
</script>
```

Comment: That's great solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use alter the style attribute using jQuery's .attr method (http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
if(status=="rejected"){
  $(.elementclass).attr("style","color:red");
}
```